# Incomprehensible usage of 'being'

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I can not understand the usage of **being** in this sentence

> He again protested about the work on the event of the planning being rejected by authority.

How is **being** used? Please explain grammatically in detail. What kind of phrase is the usage of **being**?

Comment: The title of the thread reminded me of the title of a book: "The Unbearable Lightness of Being".

Comment: It's a very difficult sentence to understand.  It's not clear how the preposition **on** is meant to be understood.  Does on mean *because* or does on mean *at the time of*.  After a reread it would appear it means *because*.  **On** is not generally a suitable substitute for *because*.

Comment: The sentence is full of mistakes.

Comment: in the event of, not on the event of

Answer (score 1):

> He again protested about the work *on the event of the planning* being rejected by authority.

I think "on the event of the planning" is intended as a description of "work", and its meaning isn't quite clear, so let's look at the sentence without it: 
the skeleton of the sentence is

> He protested about the work being rejected.

The meaning is that he protested, and what he protested about was that the work was rejected.

That is a gerund clause, or "gerund-participial clause". It functions as the complement, or object, of the preposition "about".  The subject of the clause is "work", the gerund is "being rejected" (which is a passive form).

Some other examples of that use of "being":
He liked being accepted. (direct object of "liked")
Being helpful was important to him. (subject of "was")

Going back to the deleted bit, "on the event of the planning", it would make more sense as "on the planning of the event". I suspect there's a mistake in the original.

Answer (score 1):

I analyse this (very poor) sentence differently from Jack O'Flaherty.

I think that *on the event of [the planning being rejected by authority]* is an adjunct to "protested".

I agree with Jack  that "being" forms part of a gerund-participle clause, but I believe that the clause is *the planning being rejected by authority* - "the planning" is the noun phrase which is the subject of the gerund clause.

I read the sentence as meaning

> He again protested about the work, when the planning got rejected by the authority.